# Can .NET test arrays for equivalence and not just equal references?

Tags: .net, arrays, equals

```
var a = new double[] {1, 2, 3};
var b = new double[] {1, 2, 3};
System.Console.WriteLine(Equals(a, b)); // Returns false
```

However, I'm looking for a way to compare arrays which would compare the internal values instead of refernces. Is there a built in way to do this in .NET?

Also, while I understand `Equals` comparing references, `GetHashCode` returns different values for these two arrays also, which I feel shouldn't happen, since they have the same internal values.

Comment: `GetHashCode` returns different values because they are different objects and so can both be used as keys in a dictionary or hashtable - hence they should ideally be placed in different buckets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TSource>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) method.

```
var a = new double[] {1, 2, 3};
var b = new double[] {1, 2, 3};
System.Console.WriteLine(a.SequenceEqual(b)); // Returns true
```

As far as the issue with GetHashCode returning different values, remember that you are dealing with two distinct values here. **You are not comparing arrays, you are comparing two references to arrays.**

Default equality comparison for reference types needs to be consistent. If you need something else to happen remember there is a built in model for that using [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) which allows you to define custom equality comparison based on specific needs that don't follow the standard reference equality pattern.

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE: Fixed code to use the correct comparison method (thanks to @CodesInChaos for pointing that out).

If you're in .NET 4, you can use the IStructuralEquatable interface:

```
IStructuralEquatable c = b;
Console.WriteLine(c.Equals(a, StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer));
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609823/what-problem-does-istructuralequatable-and-istructuralcomparable-solve) has more detail.

Comment: Thanks, `StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals(a, b)` is what I was looking for (where `a` and `b` are of type `System.Array`).