# fastest way for accessing double array as key in dictionary

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a `double[]` array, i want to use it as key （not literally, but in the way that the key is matched when all the doubles in the double array need to be matched)

What is the fastest way to use the `double[]` array as key to dictionary?

Is it using
`Dictionary<string, string>` (convert double[] to a string)
or
anything else like converting it

Comment: Yo do understand that two arrays with same values will give different keys (because they are not equal)?

Comment: Why would you want to use *arrays* as keys and not doubles themselves?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I have changed the question

Comment: What's wrong with Dictionary<double, string>?

Comment: @NWard basically what i need is that all doubles in the array to be matched

Comment: @jomsk1e I need all doubles in the double array to be matched

Comment: If all "arrays" have the same length, you can use `Tuple<double, double, ..., double>` since it overrides `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in the way you need. **Question:** Will all arrays have the same length?

Comment: @william007 Instead of using a dictionary here, why not create a class which stores both your array of doubles and the string value as properties?

Comment: @william007 I still have feeling that something wrong here. Can you explain what your double values mean and with what you are trying to match them?

Comment: @NWard I need to fast access the string value using the doubles

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen yes, all arrays have the same length, yes, what you provide could be an answer, if there are no faster one :)

Comment: @william007 why all arrays have same length. Each of values in array have specific meaning?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy you are right!

Comment: To be fast, the important thing is that the GetHashCode of your key is correctly implemented. That means 2 keys that should be equal must have the same hash code and 2 keys that should not be equal should have a different hash code. 
A tuple will allow that. Otherwise, you will have to develop your own IEqualityComparer.

Comment: @krimog Technically it's OK if two "unequal" keys have the same hash code - you just want to _minimize_ the collisions as much as possible.

Comment: @DStanley : That's why I said "should" and not "must".

Answer (score 3):

*Given that all key arrays will have the same length*, either consider using a `Tuple<,,, ... ,>`, or use a structural equality comparer on the arrays.

With tuple:

```
var yourDidt = new Dictionary<Tuple<double, double, double>, string>();
yourDict.Add(Tuple.Create(3.14, 2.718, double.NaN), "da value");

string read = yourDict[Tuple.Create(3.14, 2.718, double.NaN)];
```

With (strongly typed version of) `StructuralEqualityComparer`:

```
class DoubleArrayStructuralEqualityComparer : EqualityComparer<double[]>
{
    public override bool Equals(double[] x, double[] y)
    {
        return System.Collections.StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer
            .Equals(x, y);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(double[] obj)
    {
        return System.Collections.StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer
            .GetHashCode(obj);
    }
}

...

var yourDict = new Dictionary<double[], string>(
    new DoubleArrayStructuralEqualityComparer());

yourDict.Add(new[] { 3.14, 2.718, double.NaN, }, "da value");

string read = yourDict[new[] { 3.14, 2.718, double.NaN, }];
```

Also consider the suggestion by Sergey Berezovskiy to create a custom class or (immutable!) struct to hold your set of `double`s. In that way you can name your type and its members in a natural way that makes it more clear what you do. And your class/struct can easily be extended later on, if needed.

Comment: It seems the tuple approach is faster. But the problem is the size of the array is not fixed beforehand, it is a parameter input by the user. 
Can
var yourDidt = new Dictionary<Tuple<double, ...>, string>();
be created at runtime, based on the size of double array I have?
say if double array is of size four, then I need 
var yourDidt = new Dictionary<Tuple<double, double, double, double>, string>();

Comment: @william007 No, unfortunately you cannot use `Tuple` if the length is not known at compile-time. In that case, use the array solution.

Comment: No problem, I have found another way to make it even faster, which I have posted in the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Thus all arrays have same length and each item in array have specific meaning, then create class which holds all items as properties with descriptive names. E.g. instead of double array with two items you can have class `Point` with properties `X` and `Y`. Then override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` of this class and use it as key (see [What is the best algorithm for an overriding GetHashCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode)):

```
Dictionary<Point, string>
```

Benefits - instead of having array, you have data structure which makes its purpose clear. Instead of referencing items by indexes, you have nice named property names, which also make their purpose clear. And also speed - calculating hash code is fast. Compare:

```
double[] a = new [] { 12.5, 42 };
// getting first coordinate a[0];
Point a = new Point { X = 12.5, Y = 42 };
// getting first coordinate a.X
```

Comment: @william007 main benefit is that it is easy to understand and maintain :)

Answer (score 1):

[Do not consider this a separate answer; this is an extension of @JeppeStigNielsen's answer]

I'd just like to point out that you make Jeppe's approach generic as follows:

```
public class StructuralEqualityComparer<T>: IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(obj);
    }

    public static StructuralEqualityComparer<T> Default
    {
        get
        {
            StructuralEqualityComparer<T> comparer = _defaultComparer;

            if (comparer == null)
            {
                comparer = new StructuralEqualityComparer<T>();
                _defaultComparer = comparer;
            }

            return comparer;
        }
    }

    private static StructuralEqualityComparer<T> _defaultComparer;
}
```

(From an original answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5601068/106159)

Then you would declare the dictionary like this:

```
var yourDict  = new Dictionary<double[], string>(new StructuralEqualityComparer<double[]>());
```

Note: It might be better to initialise `_defaultComparer` using `Lazy<T>`.

---

[EDIT]

It's possible that this might be faster; worth a try:

```
class DoubleArrayComparer: IEqualityComparer<double[]>
{
    public bool Equals(double[] x, double[] y)
    {
        if (x == y)
            return true;

        if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;

        if (x.Length != y.Length)
            return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; ++i)
            if (x[i] != y[i])
                return false;

        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(double[] data)
    {
        if (data == null)
            return 0;

        int result = 17;

        foreach (var value in data)
            result += result*23 + value.GetHashCode();

        return result;
    }
}

...

var yourDict = new Dictionary<double[], string>(new DoubleArrayComparer());
```

Comment: I have tested, this approach seems to be slower then using 
Dictionary<string, string> and Dictionary<Tuple<double,...> string> as what have mentioned here. Dictionary<Tuple<double,...> string> works fastest. But I have a question, have listed in the comments in Jeppe post.

Comment: @william007 Is the alternative code I posted any faster?

Comment: Yes, your DoubleArrayComparer is the fastest now! I have posted a comment on the speed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is what I found so far:

I input an entry (length 4 arrray) to the dictionary, and access it for 999999 times on my machine:

`Dictionary<double[], string>(
                new DoubleArrayStructuralEqualityComparer());` takes `1.75 seconds`

`Dictionary<Tuple<double...>,string>` takes `0.85 seconds`

The code below takes `0.1755285 seconds`, which is the fastest now! (in line with the comment with Sergey.)

The fastest - The code of `DoubleArrayComparer` by Matthew Watson takes `0.15 seconds`!

```
    public class DoubleArray
    {
        private double[] d = null;
        public DoubleArray(double[] d)
        {
            this.d = d;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (!(obj is DoubleArray)) return false;

            DoubleArray dobj = (DoubleArray)obj;
                if (dobj.d.Length != d.Length) return false;

                for (int i = 0; i < d.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (dobj.d[i] != d[i]) return false;
                    }
                return true;

        }
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked // Overflow is fine, just wrap
            {
                int hash = 17;
                for (int i = 0; i < d.Length;i++ )
                {
                    hash = hash*23 + d[i].GetHashCode();
                }

                return hash;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems to me that you focus too much on speed, but even then you do not measure the speed in a particularly relevant matter. Why query a `Dictionary<,>` with only one entry that many times? I think you should focus more on which code looks and feels correct for the problem you want to solve. Regarding the code above: In `Equals` you type-check for `DoubleArray` twice. Your `GetHashCode()` can get really slow for long arrays. One could renounce on using each and every entry if the array was huge.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Thanks for the comment, I am querying it multiple time, since the concern of the performance here is the dictionary accessing time, and I believe this is a good approximation to judge how good a method is :) Regarding the GetHashCode(), do you know of any good approach given large array?

Comment: Have you measured on a dictionary with really many entries, maybe such that the key arrays are long as well? But it all depends on how you are going to use it. If the arrays have length 1000, say, will it be very common that the first `999` entries are the same, and the difference appears only late? If not, maybe stop your `for` loop early. What is fast, depends on how your data looks.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen what you saying are really making sense - we should design it according to the data.