# Declaring Inner dictionary comparer C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary as follows

```
Dictionary<ulong, Dictionary<byte[], byte[]>> Info;
```

And the inner dictionary holds a byte[] array as a key.

I am unable to understand how to declare the constructor for a the `Info` dictionary. For the inner key comparison I have `ByteArrayComparer`,

```
  public class ByteArrayComparer : IEqualityComparer<byte[]> 
    {
        public bool Equals(byte[] left, byte[] right)
        {
            if (left == null || right == null)
            {
                return left == right;
            }
            if (left.Length != right.Length)
            {
                return false;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < left.Length; i++)
            {
                if (left[i] != right[i])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        public int GetHashCode(byte[] key)
        {
            if (key == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
            int sum = 0;
            foreach (byte cur in key)
            {
                sum += cur;
            }
            return sum;
  }
}
```

Which I picked up from SO [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440392/use-byte-as-key-in-dictionary)

Please advise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The specification for the comparer wouldn't be part of the `Info` initialization directly - it would be when you create a value to *put* in the outer dictionary. For example:

```
// It's stateless, so let's just use one of them.
private static readonly IEqualityComparer<byte[]> ByteArrayComparerInstance
    = new ByteArrayComparer();

Dictionary<ulong, Dictionary<byte[], byte[]>> Info
    = new Dictionary<ulong, Dictionary<byte[], byte[]>();

....

...
Dictionary<byte[], byte[]> valueMap;

if (!Info.TryGetValue(key, out valueMap))
{
    valueMap = new Dictionary<byte[], byte[]>(ByteArrayComparerInstance);
    Info[key] = valueMap;
}
...
```

Comment: @Piotr, probably saves a few steps of manual code in writing some extraction code from the dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

When created your `Info` doesn't have any dictionaries inside so u can't realy define comparere at that step. You have to do this for each item added into `Info` object.