# Whether a Dictionary can have Array as Key?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Am Facing a problem in Dictionaries.
Whether an Array can be a Key of a Value???

```
Dictionary<string[], int> di = new Dictionary<string[], int>();
di.Add(new string[]
{
    "1","2"
}, 1);

di.Add(new string[]
{
    "2","3"
}, 2);

MessageBox.Show(di[new string[] { "2", "3" }].ToString()); // Here KeyNotFoundException occurred.
```

Why Exception?

Comment: The problem is that each array is considered different according to its `GetHashCode()`, even if they contain the same values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default only references of the arrays would be compared, so you either have to

1. provide a custom [`IEqualityComparer<string[]>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or
2. use a [`Tuple<string, string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387181%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as key instead ( since you only have two strings)

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1440395/284240) a similar question's answer which shows how to create a custom comparer for the [`Dictionary`- constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thus I need to Create a Multikeyed Dictionary of N number of Keys dynamically.. I tried a simple.. your answer gives me a way.. :-)

Comment: @GokulJai: i'm not sure if you've understood me correctly. The [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387181%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is just an alternative for your array since you're using only two strings anyway. A `Tuple` overrides `Equals` + `GetHashCode` automatically for you. If you want to use the array you need to provide a custom class that implements `IEqualityComparer<string>` which you use in the constructor of the dictionary.

Comment: yes I understood this. My `Key` array can contain one or more elements in it.. but I should use the Custom Comparer. @TimSchmelter thank you.

Answer (score 3):

No, actually you should not use arrays as a `Dictionary<>` Key; `Dictionary<>` when works with *keys* uses their **hash codes** which are computed as **addresses**:

```
String[] a = new[]{"1", "2"}; 
String[] b = new[]{"1", "2"}; 

a.GetHashCode() == b.GetHashCode(); // <- false
```

Arrays a and b have *different addresses*, and so *different hash codes* that's why

```
di.Add(a, 1); 
di[b]; // <- error since a.GetHashCode() != b.GetHashCode()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because a the Equals and GetHashCode functions of an array don't compare the content but the reference of the array himself.